Generate Conda Package Directly Using Maturin
I was wondering if it is possible to generate a Conda package directly using Maturin.
I understand that Maturin generates a .whl file which can then be used to generate a Conda package. However, I am curious if there is a way to skip this step and automatically generate the Conda package directly using the conda-build recipe command.
I have tried using the bld.bat & build.sh scripts with the maturin build command nested inside these scripts however that seems to fail.
python_rust_project/
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── recipe/
│   ├── bld.bat
│   ├── build.sh
│   └── meta.yaml
├── src/
│   ├── lib.rs
│   └── functions.rs
├── python/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── example.py
└── pyproject.toml

I understand this error is not entirely helpful.
(base) %SRC_DIR%>call "C:\Users\AppData\Local\miniforge3\Scripts\..\condabin\conda.bat" activate --stack "%BUILD_PREFIX
python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\miniforge3\\conda-bld\\lib_1724372107656\\work\\build.sy
BuildScriptException: Command '['cmd.exe', '/d', '/c', 'conda_build.bat']' returned non-zero exit status 2.


Could you share the error message from maturin build command?

I placed the error in the post; however, this is precisely what I am trying to avoid.
I want to use the bash commands in the recipe directory to generate the .whl file from conda-build recipe command. This would theoretically link the project with the wheel file and create the conda package all with one command.

Oh I see. It's strange that the maturin build returns that conda error you mentioned. Did you append it at somewhere at the end or beginning  of the build.sh. Normally, placing a command inside a script should work the same way as on the terminal. My guess is that the working directory is changed somewhere either in normal build.sh process ormaturin build can't find the expected files to perform the build. Have you tried cd the script working directory back to its original directory once it finish running regular build.sh and move on to maturin build?
